# Where is the Linked apps page

Tags: google-api, google-play

In this tutorial, it was saying about the Linked apps page.

May I know where is that page?

https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#a_create_a_linked_application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"To link your game to a Google API Console project, open the Linked apps page, and then follow the instructions specific to your platform."

Seems that there is no that page any more, instead there is

```
Play Games Services -> Setup And Management -> Configuration
```

menu option in google play console https://play.google.com/console/developers

On that page you can chose either to link your app to new or existing Google APIs project.